# NS binding aborted shown in Mozilla Firefox for Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-apps-script

I'm coding a little program by Google Apps Script which loads the data out of a Google Sheet and puts it into a few tables (see first two images).
After the page has been loaded, you can edit the data and store it back into the Google Sheet. The App runs pretty well, except on Mozilla Firefox.
Every time I want to save my data, Mozilla Firefox shows the notification "NS binding aborted" (see the third image).
I already set up a random version behind the URL (https://script.google.com/macros/s/A.....pd/exec?v=5911) but the problem is still there...

PS.: When I hit the "Speichern / Save" Button the script saves all values into a variable and sends the variable to the server where the google sheet is stored. After that, it reloads the page by clicking on an HTML-Link which is hidden at the bottom of the HTML-page.

Has somebody an idea how I can solve this problem?

[image: This is the Google Sheet]

[image: This is the WebApp]

[image]